# W32TeX and installing custom packages

Tags: packages, installing, windows

I have installed W32TeX (full) on Windows 7. I like the W32TeX because it gives me clean and minimal install. My question is - how can I install for example moderncv package and all of its dependencies? It is quite painfull to browse through CTAN and search for all dependencies of moderncv. Unpacking everything into `C:\w32tex\share\texmf-local\tex\latex`, running `mktexlsr` doesn't at all fix the problem. Any tool that will automagically install CTAN packages into W32TeX system path into directories where they belong to?

Comment: There is no 'magic' tool for this in any distro: getting files in the right places is not easy, and that is why both TeX Live and MiKTeX require human interventions to get their packages right. Is there a reason you decided against a 'minimal' installation of one of those two systems, which would allow selective addition of packages using the appropriate manager?

Comment: I didn't know there is way like this. Are there any tutorials how to do minimal TeX Live install and then do installation only of packages that I want?

Comment: Unpacking custom package into w32tex\share\texmf-local\tex\latex and running mktexlsr worked for me to install ucs package

Answer (score 2):

You can install the basic version of MiKTeX from the MiKTeX homepage [www.miktex.org](http://www.miktex.org/download).

After installing it you can find an MiKTeX package manager by clicking `Windows-Start`-> `all Programms` -> `MiKTeX 2.9` -> `Maintanance (Admin)` -> `Package Manager (Admin)`.  Here you can search (and select) for class `moderncv`.

On the website of MiKTeX you will find a manual how to install it.